# Execution order of multiple asynchronous requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

Consider the following code:

```
<div id="output"></div>
```

```js
var i, item;
var s = "Succeed";

for (i = 0 ; i < s.length ; i++){
    item = s[i];
    (function(item){
       $.get('http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/one/two').done(function(ret){
          $("<p>"+item+"</p>").appendTo($('#output'));
       });
    })(item);
}
```

How may I fix it as to get `Succeed`in the right order and not in a random one? **I want to keep the asynchronous requests**.

Comment: That depends a lot on what you mean by "right" and "wrong." But fundamentally, if you want to do them in series rather than parallel, don't start the next until the previous completes.

Comment: That's exactly what am I asking for. The way to output   S  u   c   c   e   e  d

Comment: Save item in a new array with the correct position corresponding to i and print the array every time if you want to see imediate results

Answer (score 0):

The are two ways to achieve your goal is to separate async requests with actual drawing.

1. Separate async requests with actual drawing

   - Get all items using async requests and put them to the list
   - Sort the list after all items received and show it to user
2. Introduce slot system or position index of the received item